# оптимизация отображения datatable ajax используя laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, datatable

Есть страничка которая отображает данные с бд ,данный отчет формируется по дате .Я написал контроллер который возвращает json ДЛЯ  view . И на отображает данные используя jquery datateble . Запрос к контроллеру отправляется с использованием  ajax.Но  так как много данных загрузка в таблицу происходит очень медленно . Можно ли как то оптимизировать отображение .

```
<div  style="margin-top: 20px">
            <table   class="here_table" id="reporttable" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <td >ID</td>
        <td width="300px">Дата</td>
        <td>Терминал</td>
        <td>Сумма</td>
        <td width="20px">Коммиссия</td>
        <td>Реквизит</td>
        <td style="width: 200px">Услуга</td>
        <td width="20px">Статус</td>
        <td>Чек</td>
        <td>Время проведения</td>
        </thead>
                <tbody class="style_td_center" id="item">


                </tbody>

                <tfoot class="pay-info">
                <td colspan="2" style="background: #0d6aad;color: #fff;" id="all_pay">Всего платежей
                    @isset($paymentsinfo)
                        {{$paymentsinfo[0]->count}}
                    @else
                        0
                    @endisset</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="background: #0d6aad;color: #fff;"  id="all_sum">На сумму
                    @isset($paymentsinfo)
                        {{$paymentsinfo[0]->allsum}}
                    @else
                        0
                    @endisset</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="background: #0d6aad;color: #fff;"  id="all_com">Общая коммиссия
                    @isset($paymentsinfo)
                        {{$paymentsinfo[0]->allcommission}}
                    @else
                        0
                    @endisset</td>
                </tfoot>
            </table>



    </div>


</div>
    </div>
@endsection

<script>

    function getMessage(){

        var startdate=$("#startdate").val();
        var enddate =$("#enddate").val();
        var service=$("#service").val();
        var terminal=$("#terminal").val();
        var status=$("#status").val();

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type:'POST',
            url:'{{route('payment')}}',
            data: {startdate: startdate,enddate:enddate,service:service,terminal:terminal,status:status},

            success: function (response) {


                payments=response.payments;
                table
                    .clear()
                    .draw();
                var content ="";

                for(i=0; i<payments.length; i++) {

                    table.row.add(
                        [
                            payments[i].id,
                            payments[i].created_at,
                            payments[i].terminal,
                            payments[i].sum,
                            payments[i].commission,
                            payments[i].dst,
                            payments[i].service,
                            payments[i].status,
                            '<a style="color: black" class="btn btn-warning" href="/printcheck/'+payments[i].id+'">Печать чека</a>',

                            Math.abs( payments[i].difference),
                        ]
                    ).draw();





                }


                $('#all_pay').text("Всего платежей : "+response.paymentsinfo[0].count)
                $('#all_sum').text("На сумму : "+response.paymentsinfo[0].allsum)
                $('#all_com').text("Общая коммиссия : "+response.paymentsinfo[0].allcommission)


            },



        });
    }
```

Comment: Да, можно постраничной навигацией. DataTable дает возможность для каждой страницы делать ajax запрос на сервер, куда можете указать лимит и страницу.

Comment: можете показать пример запроса

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side